# Why do downloads that fail with error "NETWORK_FAILED" in firefox have the property "canResume" set to false? How can they be restarted in code?

Tags: firefox, download, javascript, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

I'm trying to fix the defunct Firefox plugin ["auto resume downloads"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-resume-downloads/).

It appears that to restart a download, one can invoke (from a plugin or Firefox's plugin inspector console) [`downloads.resume`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/resume) function (passing in the `id` of the failed download). However, the download, of type [DownloadItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/DownloadItem), has its property `canResume` set to `false` if the `error` is `"NETWORK_FAILED"`. The documentation doesn't seem to give any indication of *why* `canResume` is false. One can resume the download manually through the GUI by clicking the little reload icon next to said download. Manually setting `canResume` to `true` causes the property value to update without error, however it still can't be `resumed` and the property is reset to `false` after the next tick.

**How can I programmatically resume a Firefox download that's failed due to error "NETWORK_FAILED"?**

Comment: please note I believe this is a Super User question instead of a web development or Javascript question as the answer deals with the inner workings of a specific piece of software, that being Firefox. That the software can be interacted with via Javascript is incidental. I've seen similar questions related to firefox extensions here in the Super User stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was raised in February 2021 in the post
[A mismatch occurs between Retry button and canResume property](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/a-mismatch-occurs-between-retry-button-and-canresume-property/75867).

The answer by Martin Giger was:

> The API (in Firefox) doesn’t currently support retrying by resuming, afaik.

The poster insisted on this as a bug, and the answer was:

> There are currently no bugs filed asking for it, last I checked (even though it technically is a parity bug, as far as I understand, since chrome supports it).

The final answer is then that canResume is set to false because Firefox
has simply not implemented resume in this case.

You may signal it as a bug in http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/, or use another
browser than Firefox where this was implemented.

Comment: Might using wget be an alternative?

Comment: ...  i.e. using `--continue` or `--start-pos`

Comment: You may replace Firefox with any downloader that supports resume. I myself never use a browser for large downloads, since browsers are not very good on resume. A good downloader will also support multi-threading, useful if one thread can't manage to fully use the available bandwidth.

Comment: could you recommend the one you use?

Comment: I mostly use [Free Download Manager](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/).

Comment: FDM does not work in cases where download portals are being used, since the site requires a dynamic folder code and token to be passed before download is authorised

Comment: @Shawn: I have since moved to [Ant Download Manager](https://antdownloadmanager.com/), but I don't know if it will do better.